# HQL not equal and not in Query is not working

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hql

```
@Query("SELECT i FROM ICD10CM i WHERE i.type NOT IN ('C') AND i.name LIKE %:icdString% OR i.code LIKE %:icdString% OR i.desc LIKE %:icdString%")
    List<ICD10CM> getICD10CMBySearch(@Param("icdString") String icdString);
```

I'm getting the list of `ICD10CM` along with which have `Type` C, I want List of other than `Type` C.
I Tried `not in ('C')`,`i.type != 'C'`,tried `<>` and also tried `NOT LIKE C%`.
I want HQL Query for this not a native Query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try build a proper like condition using concat 
and build a proper OR condition using  ()

```
  @Query("SELECT i 
    FROM ICD10CM i 
    WHERE i.type NOT IN ('C') 
    AND ( 
      i.name LIKE concat('%',:icdString,'%') 
      OR i.code LIKE  concat('%',:icdString,'%') 
      OR i.desc LIKE  concat('%',:icdString,'%')
    )")
      List<ICD10CM> getICD10CMBySearch(@Param("icdString") String icdString);
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you use `or` :

```
OR i.code LIKE %:icdString% OR i.desc LIKE %:icdString%
```

change `or` to `and`